# How to set flag for correct PCRE? / g_regex_split_full: assertion 'regex != NULL' failed

Tags: makefile, pcre, glib, ldflags

When calling

```
tokens = g_regex_split (arv_gv_device_get_url_regex (), filename, 0);
```

I am stumbling into this error

```
(process:15239): GLib-WARNING **: unknown option bit(s) set
(process:15239): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_regex_split_full: assertion 'regex != NULL' failed
```

[g_regex_split](http://docs.factorcode.org:8080/content/word-g_regex_split_full,glib.ffi.html) is part of glib.

Searching online makes me believe that the error could be related to the compiler referencing the wrong pcre (=Perl Compatible Regular Expressions library). (see discussion of similar error here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mu-discuss/cy_yKE6ivzM)

How would i define what pcre my compiler picks up? What flag do i set in my Makefile?

---

**ADDITIONAL INFO**

```
$ locate libpcre.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so
```

and

```
$ dpkg -s libpcre3
Package: libpcre3
Status: install ok installed
Priority: required
Section: libs
Installed-Size: 466
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Multi-Arch: same
Source: pcre3
Version: 1:8.31-2
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
Pre-Depends: multiarch-support
Breaks: approx (<< 4.4-1~), cduce (<< 0.5.3-2~), cmigrep (<< 1.5-7~), galax (<< 1.1-7~), libpcre-ocaml (<< 6.0.1~), liquidsoap (<< 0.9.2-3~), ocsigen (<< 1.3.3-1~)
Conflicts: libpcre3-dev (<= 4.3-3)
Description: Perl 5 Compatible Regular Expression Library - runtime files
This is a library of functions to support regular expressions whose syntax
and semantics are as close as possible to those of the Perl 5 language.
.
This package contains the runtime libraries.
Original-Maintainer: Mark Baker <mark@mnb.org.uk>
```

Comment: What version of pcre is installed on your system? Do you have multiple versions of pcre installed on your system?

Comment: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 and /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.1

Answer (score 0):

The `regex != NULL` assertion failure will happen when you pass NULL to `g_regex_split` which, in your case, would mean that the return value of `arv_gv_device_get_url_regex` is `NULL`.  It sounds like you're creating the regex without checking to make sure that it actually succeeds.

As for why `g_regex_new` doesn't succeed, you didn't include that code so it's hard to answer, but the warning about "unknown option bit(s) set" definitely provides a clue.  Take a close look at what flags you're passing to `g_regex_new` and figure out which one(s) are causing that warning—fixing that will probably make `g_regex_new` return an actual instance instead of `NULL`, which should fix the assertion failure.  Of course, you should still check the return value at runtime and handle errors appropriately instead of letting them turn into assertion failures…